# Filter Visual Studio 2013 TFS merge to only files that have actually changed

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, merge, visual-studio-2013

I am doing a merge between two branches and TFS/Visual Studio 2013 is identifying 1800 files required to be merged.  However, doing a diff between the two branches shows that there are only ~100 that are actually different.

The pending changes window mostly corroborates this, as all files are listed with a [merge] status except those which have actually changed; those have a [merge, edit] status.

Is there a way to filter the pending changes list to only show files which are really changed so I can do inspect the differences visually?  It is very error prone to have to scroll through and manually do this, skipping items that show only [merge].

My current alternative would be to do a diff on the branches, and specifically look in the pending changes window at files which are identified as different, but that is rather cumbersome for something that should be simple.

Edit: Here is a screenshot of the pending changes window. I only care about the items which are [merge,edit] as it means there is a change and I want to see the diff.  Conflicts will be shown in the Resolve Conflicts window.  I don't care about [merge] items, as they are identical.  There are 1000s of files with no changes, but I want to single out the ones that have changed and inspect the diff.

[image: PendingChangesWindow]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: @LukkhaCoder I added a screenshot.

Comment: Ironically, vs2010 can this, so if you have a copy lying around you can use that.  Since you specifically tagged your question for vs2013 I'm guessing you already know that, but I thought I'd throw it in just in case.

Comment: Would love this feature. It's been asked on MSDN forums and internal mailing lists as well.

Answer (score 11):

Try the following trick:
In **Team Explorer**, **Ctrl+A** all the included changes, right click and select **Undo...**

You'll get the **Undo Pending Changes** dialog with all the items selected. First of all, *uncheck everything*.  Then observe that you have a column named **Change** and you can sort by it to have all the [Merge] changes stacked together, and you can check them all together and undo only them with a single click.

Answer (score 2):

There is a tool which achieves that, "qbus vMerge" - which is a Visual Studio 2012/2013 plugin available in the Visual Studio Gallery. But it's only free for team projects with up to 5 registered users. In the pre-check-in dialog, you can filter the changes by Edits, Deletes and Adds.

Link:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/cb2f3f5b-7cea-4f2b-9d47-0e51b2619bd0

Confession: i am one of the contributors.

Comment: Does vMerge support VS 15/17?

Answer (score 2):

You can do the merge and before checking in the files, just compare your branch folder with the latest version. So if you are merging from anywhere **into** `branch-Servicing` for example, Compare `$/branch-Servicing` with `your local workspace for that branch`:

[image: TFS Source Control Explorer Compare View for merge changes]

You will get a list of all files that are binary different. With a simple double click, you can view the diff.

Comment: my VS2013 will not accept a folder in either part of this dialogue.

Comment: @fastmultiplication You can directly select compare from the context menu of the target folder in source control explorer. maybe I installed tfs power tools and/or vs productivity extensions from Microsoft in order to be able to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to view **all** changes in a merge, excluding merge-only with no changes, the easiest way is to run `tf diff` from the VS command line.  This will use the diff tool on all changed files.  I believe this shows adds as well as edits.  I do wish you could sort the pending changes window by type of change action like in previous versions.

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with the same issue. ChangeType used to be a column that was available in the list view of vs 2012 pending changes. I was hoping it would be added to 2015, but no such luck.

Here is a command-line way of doing this against the pending changes:

tf status {pathToWorkspace} /format:brief /recursive | find ", " > c:\merge.txt

ex:

tf status c:\tfs\main /format:brief /recursive | find ", " > c:\merge.txt

It's not pretty, but at least it gets the filtered list easily.

Answer (score -1):

Summary of: http://thesoftwarecondition.com/blog/2011/05/01/tfs-pending-changes-ignoring-files-which-are-identical-to-the-originals/

**Method 1: TFS Power Tools**

Install TFS Power Tools and execute `tfpt uu /noget /r *` in the root of the branch. As a result, TFS will go through and undo checkouts for any unchanged files whilst leaving your modified files untouched.

**Method 2: Undo Checkout**

Another option is to "Undo Checkout" all the changes, and clicking "No to All" when asked to confirm for undo checkout. This way Visual Studio will "undo checkout" all the files that are not changed, and all the changed files will remain checked out. 
Drawback: this method undoes renames.

Comment: But a merge pending change *isn't* an "unchanged" item that can simply be undone without penalty.  A merge pending change establishes a new baseline for the two branches.  You should check it in.

Comment: While [merge] pending change need to be checked-in, that can be done later after reviewing and checking-in the [edit, merge] changes.
So I think this is a valid solution, at least "Method 2", method 1 didn't work for me.

Answer (score -5):

My question would be why do you care?

If you do the merge TFS will figure out at run time that the files do not need modification and you will not see them as changed in the annotate tool. However if you pick-and-choose the files to merge you will leave a bunch of "pending merges" hanging around that you will have to deal with later anyway...

If there are conflicts TFS will highlight them to you for dealing with.

If you do need to compare before you merge you can use the built in diff tool in Visual Studio that will let you diff a branch (or just folders) local->local, local->Server or Server->server.

[image]

Comment: I care because I want to review the changes that TFS is merging?  For files that are identical, I don't need to review them.  I'm not trying to pick and choose what files to merge, I'm trying to choose what files I need to manually inspect in a diff tool.  TFS will highlight conflicts (when a file was changed in both source and target), and I can deal with those in the conflict window.  I am curious to see files that changed on the source but not the target and look at the diff.

Comment: I'll give you an example of why, as well.  Some files (like versioninfo.properties in the screenshot I added) have differences that TFS can merge no problem.  However, I don't _want_ those changes to be merged as-is.  I need to either let TFS merge and edit the file before checkin, or manually merge just that file with the /discard option.  These are the kinds of inadvertent changes I am looking to avoid by doing a code review on changed files.

Comment: You can do a merge and then compare with the original to see what had been actually changes?

Comment: Track changesets stops working after 10000 files. This means that if you have more than 10000 files in TFS will lose this feature unless you go through the manual process of eliminating files that were not changed.